# State Machine Question

Tags: c#, events, thread-safety, c#-2.0, state-machine

There is a State Machine with two Transitions in the same function.

```
static readonly object _object = new object();

lock (_object)
{
    // I want Host received the event of SMTrans01 first .
    Obj.StateMachine.Send((int)MyStateMachine.EventType.SMTrans01, new object[2] { Obj, MyStateMachine.EventType.SMTrans01 });
}

lock (_object)
{
    // And then I want Host received the event of SMTrans02.
    Obj.StateMachine.Send((int)MyStateMachine.EventType.SMTrans02, new object[2] { Obj, MyStateMachine.EventType.SMTrans02 });
}
```

I implemented my state machine code as above. I am not sure I understand `Lock` statement correctly or not?

I need the events followed the the right order (Host received SMTrans01 first, and then host received SMTrans02 event).

After testing I found sometime host will receive the SMTrans02 event first. Looks like `Lock` statement not work. I don't know why.

Are there any good methods to approach it?

Comment: For locking I would not use a static object - or do you really need a lock over all instances of your object? I would otherwise consider to move to a real singleton instead and still work without a static lock.

Comment: @weismat. I just want to control my events to follow the right order. I don't really need `Lock`. I guess I don't need using `lock` actually. But I don't find other solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem has nothing to do with threads and locking.

I suspect that your Send method is asynchronous. The solution is to use a synchronous approach instead. Do not send the second event until you get an acknowledgement that the first event has been handled.

Alternatively, rewrite your receiving code so that it *can* handle the events coming out of order.

If you provide the code for `Send` and describe more how your method is being called that would help debugging the problem.

Comment: I think you understand my problem completely. Thanks for your input. I agree my problem has nothing to do with threads and locking. I just try to find a solution. Then I tried `lock`.

Answer (score 1):

if the order matters

```
EventType _state = EventType.SMTrans02;
if(_state == EventType.SMTrans02 )
{
 _state =EventType.SMTrans01;
  Obj.StateMachine.Send((int)_state, new object[2] { Obj, _state });

}
else
{
_state = EventType.SMTrans02;
Obj.StateMachine.Send((int)_state, new object[2] { Obj, _state });
}
```

for more complex situation you may use switch block or even  use  [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

you need Lock only to sync the threads which may call those events.

Comment: Yes. I got several of state machines and complex transitions. I am doing some testing with your method. thank you.